# How to pastebinit in Vim?

Tags: vim, pastebin

Following [Openwest 2015 - Erik Falor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MquaityA1SM)
I am trying to post a text via `pastebinit` from `vim` (and `nvim`) with:

1. `%!pastebinit` -- it cuts all the text of the file, pushes to pastebin and leaves the pastebin link in the file
2. copy to `"a` register and `"a!pastebinit` (or `"a!pastebinit -i -`) probably pushes to the pastebin, but doesn't show any output (unlike other shell commands)

-- how to do it right?

Can one open a register for editing, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in commandline mode, which opens command history for executing edited commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:%w !pastebinit
```

will send the whole buffer to `pastebinit` and echo the url of your paste.

You can use a range:

```
:.w !pastebinit
:10,24w !pastebinit
```

Or visual selection:

```
vjjj
:'<,'>w !pastebinit
```

See `:help :w_c`.

You can turn that into a practical custom command with:

```
" Mac OS X
command! -range=% Paste silent execute <line1> . "," . <line2> . "w !pastebinit | tr -d '\\n' | pbcopy"

" Other Unices
command! -range=% Paste silent execute <line1> . "," . <line2> . "w !pastebinit | tr -d '\\n' | xclip -i -selection clipboard"
```

Comment: FWIW, I have [a bunch of similar commands](http://vpaste.net/YAFeQ) for minimal pastebins in my `vimrc`.